# Question from the British Mathematical Olympiad

Tags: contest-math, latin-square

**Question:**

A $5×5$ square is divided into 25 unit squares. One of the numbers $1,2,3,4,5$ is inserted into each of the unit squares in such away that each row, each column and each of the two diagonals contains each of the five numbers once and only once. The sum of the numbers in the four squares immediately below the diagonal from top left to bottom right is called the *score*. Show that it is impossible for the *score* to be 20. What is the highest possible *score*?

**What have I done so far:**

The only possible way to reach 20 in the row immediately below the diagonal is by adding four 5s, i.e., $5+5+5+5=20$. It follows that all the squares in those particular four squares immediately below the diagonal must be filled with 5. We show that this is impossible given the statement of the problem.

**Proof**

Assume for the sake of contradiction that such a *score* is possible. We call two squares *adjacent* if they share any common edge. It it given in the statement of the problem that the diagonals contain all the given integers *exactly* once. Hence it follows that the diagonal above our problem set of squares must contain *exactly* one five. It also follows that at least two squares containing 5s each must be *adjacent* to each other in a row or a column. Hence it is impossible to contain four 5s in the given set of squares. Going back, we conclude that it is impossible for the score to be 20.

The part where I am stuck is finding the maximum possible *score*. I am guessing that all the integers in the four squares have to be distinct but I cannot seem to prove it.

Thank you.

Comment: Since each row and column contains each of the 5 numbers once and only once. So that means maximum score should be 14.

Comment: Example with *score* $17$ $(3+4+5+5)$: $$1 2 4 3 5 \\ 3 5 2 4 1 \\ 5 4 3 1 2 \\ 4 1 5 2 3 \\ 2 3 1 5 4$$

Comment: Is this a running math-contest ?

Comment: $$\pmatrix{3&5&4&2&1\cr 5&1&2&3&4\cr2&4&5&1&3\cr1&2&3&4&5\cr4&3&1&5&2\cr}$$ shows that 17 is possible, and I think I convinced myself that 18 is impossible. I also spent 20 minutes looking for a 4x4 version because I think we have done that here earlier.

Comment: A brute-force approach should be feasible.

Comment: @Peter: yes, brute-force approach shows that max score is $17$. Brute approach (without any optimization): $5!$ cases for each row, so $120^5 \approx 2.49\times 10^{10}$ cases totally (not so much).